# Android sdk doesn't contain tools folder

Tags: android

My Android sdk doesn't contain tools folder though it contains build-tools,platform-tools. I cannot start my SDK manager.
"Error message: Failed to execute tools\android.bat.
The system cannot find the file specified."
[image]

Comment: If you are seeing inside the correct folder `~\android-sdk\tools` and not `~\android-sdks\ ` then just re-install the sdk.

Comment: @RohanKandwal Please see the edits.. I have added a screen shot :)

Comment: your SDK seems to be missing the tools folder please reinstall it

Answer (score 0):

The `/tools` directory should definitely be there in the SDK.
It's possible you have a bad copy of the SDK.

Consider re-downloading it at:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Direct SDK-only download at:
http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.3-windows.zip

If it still comes without the /tools directory then I'd recommend posting something on the ADT-DEV forum at:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adt-dev

Answer (score 0):

see your platform-tools folder.

tools folder was in old version.its changed to platform-tools in new version of sdk

Comment: This is wrong. You can verify this by actually looking inside your SDK directory. The `android` script has always been in the `/tools` directory. Perhaps you are referring to the `adb` script which indeed moved to `/platform-tools`. Consider removing your answer

Comment: If that is the case, sdk manager would have automatically reffered to the platform-tools folder. I think your inference is true @MichaelBarany